# How to have two buttons change title and do two different functions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I'm using Objective-C to make a stopwatch. I already have a basic stop watch with 3 buttons: Start, Stop and reset. Here is my code for viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)Start:(id)start
{
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self          selector:@selector(addingthetime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)Stop:(id)sender
{
    [Timer invalidate];
}

-(IBAction)Restart:(id)sender
{
    [Timer invalidate];
    addingtheTime = 0;
    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.00"];
}

-(void)addingthetime
{
    addingtheTime = addingtheTime + 0.01;
    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", addingtheTime];
}

@end
```

And here is my code for viewcontroller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

float addingtheTime;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
    NSTimer *Timer;
}

@end
```

So my question is how do I make the Start button do the following once clicked:

1. Start the timer
2. Change the title to stop
   (Click the same button again)
3. Stop the timer
4. Change the title to start

So the aim is to have only one button which starts and stops the timer but please I want the title to change as well.

Don't worry about the reset button as I want that to remain by itself.

PS. Please explain things clearly because I find it really hard to understand some things and I am a beginner so try and keep it fairly simple thanks, and sorry if the question isn't clear.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

float addingtheTime;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

    NSTimer *Timer;

}

@end
```

In the ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.
}

-(void)addingthetime
{
    addingtheTime = addingtheTime + 0.01;
    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", addingtheTime];
}

- (IBAction)startOrStopAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    // stop
    if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"stop"]) {

        [Timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

        [sender setTitle:@"start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    // start
    else {

        if (!Timer) {
            Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(addingthetime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }else {
            [Timer setFireDate:[NSDate date]];
        }

        [sender setTitle:@"stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}


@end
```

The result:

In iPhone:

[image]

In iPad:

[image]

Comment: Hey unfortunately when i run this it crashes my iPad ;( Sorry and thanks. Don't know what caused it!!!

Comment: @MattPidd does it crash on iphone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button.tag` property to achieve this. By Default the `button.tag` property have `0`. So assume that 0 is a state when timer is Not started and 1 is the state when timer is started. You can manipulate .tag property according to your custom logic.

```
-(IBAction)Start:(id)start
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)start;
    if (button.tag == 0){
        button.tag = 1;
        [button setTitle:@"Stop" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self          selector:@selector(addingthetime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }else {
         button.tag = 0;
        [button setTitle:@"Stop" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //Invoke your method to stop Timer.
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem, I tend to avoid the tag property b/c many developers still use the viewWithTag methods for locating views.  I'd probably just have a BOOL flag in the view controller or maybe an enum for the "state" in case you need other situations covered.

Comment: Hey, I tried this out but it gave me this error message: "No visible @interface  for UIButton declares the selector setTitle:forControlState: This is probably really simple to fix but I'm just a beginner. I got this message on two lines. One line is:  [button setTitle:@"Stop" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal]; - Thanks a lot for  help in advance. (I know I'm dumb ;)
 - and the other line is  [button setTitle:@"Start" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];